# dictionary, comps and has maps

Tags: python, dictionary

I have written a code and run it, and it works fine. But I wanted to understand what is happening in the following:

```
nums = [4, 5, 1, 8]
target = 12

def TwoSum(nums, target):
    comps = dict()
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        comp = target - nums[i]
        if nums[i] in comps:
            return [comps[nums[i]], i]
        else:
            comps[comp] = i

print(TwoSum(nums, target))
```

I understand that this is using a `dict`, and the idea is to add elements from `nums` to it, then doing `target - nums[i]` and then checking if this is in the dict, and if it is, then returning the indices of the two numbers that sum to the target.

But how is `comps = dict()` used? Is it necessary? Because in the code it doesn't seem to be storing anything! Except for the last line it is used- but I don't understand what it does- can someone please explain?

Comment: `comps[comp] = i` is storing the key-value pair comp, i in dictionary comps.  `comps = dict()` creates the dictionary comps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your code was using `self` as first argument of `TwoSum`. It should be eliminated given that this is a static function, not a class method. (**Fixed**).

The line `comp = dict()` is an initialization of `comp` to an empty `dict`. It could be written in a more pythonic way: `comp = {}`.

`comp` appears to store the complement (the difference between `target` and `nums[i]`) as `comps[diff] = i`. Thereafter, when you examine a number `nums[j]`, if the complement is already in `comps`, that `j` and the corresponding previous `i` is the pair of indices you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Pierre, it now makes sense. I have made the amendments, taking out 'self' and changing the initialisation (though I know you said this is just a matter of syntax difference).   However, now I am getting a 'argument of type 'int' is not utterable for the 'if' statement and the final line of code. For the final line, I have taken out the first argument, so only (nums,target) remain. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In our case, it stores number as a key thats required to find a target, and index of opposit number in nums as value.
So, for example, when we have target at 12 and nums `[4,5,1,8]` , at the iteration on the number 4, 8->0 will be added to comps, when iteration will get to the number 8, we will check if we have number 8 in comps, and then return value of that number in comps, which is 0, and index of current iterating number, which is 3.